# Can Typescript automatically detect the types of function arguments and then use those types in the function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

To explain what I want here's an example. Supposing I have an array shuffle function I want to be able to do this:

```ts
type shuffleArray = (someType[])=>someType[]
```

Where `someType` isn't declared anywhere but inferred when an argument is passed to the function instead of having to pass the generic type argument in advance like so:

```ts
type shuffleArray<T> = (T[])=>T[]
```

Ideally, I could then use `someType` on variables inside the body of the function. I don't know if there is a way of doing this and I couldn't find one but it seems like it should be doable.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzgFgVwGZIDYQIICcsEMRQC8UAPACoB8AFLgFxRkDaAugJREUMsBQ3AxgHsAdjGCxEKdNjwh68ZGkw58RKDSwBzdoU65N3IA   is ti works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using generics, you can either do this:

```
type MyFunctionType<T> = (param: T) => T[]
```

and here indeed, you have to manually specify the type each time you use the function, or this:

```
type MyFunctionType = <T>(param: T) => T[]
```

and here you let your function INFER what's passed to the function.

More info here: [Required vs inferred generic types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225839/required-vs-inferred-generic-types-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use generics without using generics. You should use generics and solve the problem by declaring an interface that contains the methods you want to use:

```js
interface YourType {
  someMethod: () => void;
}

class YourActualType {
    public someMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}

class AnotherType {
    public someMethod() {
        // Do something else
    }
}

function shuffleArray(values: YourType[]): YourType[] {
    values.forEach(value => value.someMethod());
    return values;
}

const values = [
    new YourActualType(),
    new AnotherType()
];

shuffleArray(values);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJoHsCuUAqBPABxQG8AoZZAZ3QFsIBZCMAC3QBMAuZACgEpkAvAD5kAN3TA2AblIBfUqQQAbOJUposUAIIIwmOEvxFkZChQKYARkuAIqtBk1Zs+J8mY8B6T8gAi6ezoWUABzdwp5eUUVNWQtEHQWaCMScOQLa1tAxxZ2V1MPM28-AOog5lDkCCVKCDTIhRhMEF1gdBAqZkwYGCUILSgoODxuUQNMCEouDGwUgG0AXV5pzXmFtw8xpQnKADoYdCgAUURmUfGUYTEL3bKc5z5eGQ8oJmwOrZ2ZKIR2yjBrttJoJkHM0iAIAB3DTYHR6AwpPgAGnBULiCSSuEIED4pAWMlIlC6PT6AyGI0+kyeQA).