# Force argument object with a certain key

Tags: typescript, types

This seems like something fairly simple, but I have tried searching it multiple ways and couldn't find an answer.

I want to specify a type for an argument that allows any objects that contain a certain key, like this:

```
type Action = {type : string};
function reducer(state : object, action : object extends Action) {
    ...
};
```

Something like this, but this syntax doesn't work. That is, I want the action argument only to accept objects that contain the key "type" that is a string. If I just do this:

```
function (state : object, action : {type : string}) {...};
```

The function only accepts objects that only have the key "type". How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic for this:

```
function testFn<T extends { type: string }>(obj: T) {
  return obj;
}

testFn({ a: 2, type: 'hey' }); // Fine
testFn({ type: 'hello' }); // Fine

testFn({ a: 2 }); // Type error
testFn({ a: 2, type: 3 }); // Type error
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But I thought generics had to pass similarly to a argument. Why don't I have to pass the type to testFn, as in: `testFn<ActionWithMore>({type: 'foo', more: 'stuff'})`?

Comment: TypeScript is smart enough to infer the generic based off the input argument. It sees the type of `obj` passed in, it then ensures that it extends what we said T has to extend. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225839/required-vs-inferred-generic-types-in-typescript

Comment: Ok, cool. I've accepted your answer because it answers my question. But I have now realized I simplified my question too much, so that the answer to it does not actually help me solve my problem, so I guess I'll have to ask another question which gives more details about the real situation.